# Cannot modify the value of a Spark config: spark.executor.instances

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 3.0 and I am setting parameters

My parameters:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark.conf.set("fs.s3a.fast.upload.buffer", "bytebuffer")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes",134217728)
spark.conf.set("spark.executor.instances", 4)
spark.conf.set("spark.executor.memory", 3)
```

Error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Cannot modify the value of a Spark config: spark.executor.instances
```

**I DONT want to pass it through spark-submit as this is pytest case that I am writing.**

How do I get through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add those option to `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` before initialize SparkContext. Its syntax is similar to `spark-submit`.

Answer (score 2):

According to spark official documentation, the `spark.executor.instances` property may not be affected when setting programmatically through SparkConf in runtime, so it would be suggested to set through configuration file or spark-submit command line options.

> Spark properties mainly can be divided into two kinds: one is related
> to deploy, like “**spark.driver.memory**”, “**spark.executor.instances**”,
> **this kind of properties may not be affected when setting
> programmatically through SparkConf in runtime**, or the behavior is
> depending on which cluster manager and deploy mode you choose, so it
> would **be suggested to set through configuration file or spark-submit
> command line options**; another is mainly related to Spark runtime
> control, like “spark.task.maxFailures”, this kind of properties can be
> set in either way.

Comment: So i am writing a pytest case here and i dont know how to write pytest in combination with spark-submit.can you pleae tell me

Comment: You can specify the configuration when starting SparkSession using its config method, eg: `spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.executor.instances', 4).getOrCreate()`